# What is the CR of an animal companion?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, character-templates

The [Celestial Servant](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/feats/racial-feats/celestial-servant-aasimar) feat allows a Pathfinder aasimar character to grant their animal companion the [Celestial](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/templates/celestial-creature-cr-special) template. Among the benefits of this template is that the templated creature gains spell resistance equal to 5 + its CR.

How is the CR of an animal companion (and thus, its spell resistance) calculated?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Per James Jacobs on the Paizo forums](http://paizo.com/threads/rzs2l7ns&page=504?Ask-James-Jacobs-ALL-your-Questions-Here#25174), you should use the character's effective druid level as the animal companion's CR for purposes of this feat specifically and also similar feats/abilities:

> > > > Following up on the Celestial Servant question, how am I supposed to calculate the CR of my mount, to figure out its spell resistance? I browsed the Bestiary, but could find any pattern to go by.
> > >
> > > Animal companions, mounts, familiars, and the like do not have CR scores. Use your character's CR (this equals your character's total character level minus 1) instead as the SR baseline.
> >
> > I thought the Level minus one for CR was because NPCS have less gear than PCS? I always assumed that a PC's CR would be their level because of their gear.
>
> That's a great point.
>
> Makes it even easier to figure the companion's SR too, so that's good as well!
>
> So, yeah. Your character level = your CR for the purposes of determining a celestial companion's SR.

Comment: @aloisdg Please don't quote text using a picture. We have the ability to quote text here with copy-paste technology, which makes it searchable.

Answer (score 2):

Since animal companions are a class feature, they don't get factored into the party's APL (or CR, for enemies), but you can still ballpark them for the purposes of that feat as well as similar mechanics.

The simplest way is to compare their statistics to those listed in the [Monster Creation Guide](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/bestiary/monsterCreation.html#table-1-1-monster-statistics-by-cr). Find the line that most closely matches their hp, AC, attacks, and saves. You should end up close to one row, and if you have to choose between two, pick the lower. Then, apply the template and add 1 to the CR if they have 5 HD or more, as it states.

Answer (score -1):

Considering that an animal companion is more a feature of a character than a character in its own right it must have CR0 - otherwise it'd be factored in during encounter calculations. And [Druids](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/core-classes/druid#TOC-Nature-Bond-Ex-) with Animal Companions aren't calculated any different from those without.

To make this less-weird (and useless) though I would suggest HD-1 as that's generally the [calculation](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/gamemastering#Table-Encounter-Design) for players in their own right.